# How to track Google Play download sources

Tags: google-analytics, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I can't find the simple answer for a simple question. I want to generate a link to my app on Google Play and check how many installs comes from this link.
For iOS this is very simple, you just go to the analytics ->sources and generate a link that has a parameter. I can't find anything like that in Google Play Developer Console. Am I missing something or there is not such option for GP?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Firebase Dynamic Links.

More information here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links

Answer (score 1):

You can create Dynamic Links using your own domain name:

```
https://example.com/summer-sale
https://example.com/links/promos/summer-sale
https://links.example.com/summer-sale
https://ex.amp.le/summer-sale
```

Or, if you don't have a domain for your app, you can use a free custom page.link subdomain:

EXAMPLE LINK: https://example.page.link/summer-sale

Create your free subdomain in the Firebase console.

All Dynamic Links features, including analytics, post-install attributions, and SDK integrations, work with both custom page.link domains and your own domain.